# How to setup godaddy task scheduler(windows plesk)

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks

after setting up the task scheduler on godaddy server (windows)

Path to an executable file * `C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP54\php-cgi.exe`

and Arguments to `G:\PleskVhosts\subdomain.domain.com\auto_reminder.php`

I got this email

```
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-type: text/html
No input file specified.
```

anyone knows how to setup properly?thanks

Answer (score 0):

check which path of the auto reminder.php file is correct. It works for me with WHMCS on On Plesk Windows.[image]

[image]
This is the content of received email